# Parameterized query returns wrong data type

Tags: sql-server

Please bear with me, I am a beginner with SQL and now I have been stuck on an issue for hours. Often every little question I have is already answered here in the forum so I have not had any reason to post before.

I am currently in the process of writing queries for a statistics dashboard and hit the wall on this one:

OmbudID and Grupp are integers
Födelsedatum and Startdatum are dates

Without using UNION the Query works just fine, the parameters @start and @slut works just as expected when values are given from the TimePicker, but as soon as I use UNION the Query seems to convert the parameters with the expected value to be varchar(3). I tried to CAST Startdatum AS Date but that only gives me the expected value varchar(1024).

I have tried multiple different solutions with no avail, so I turn to you guys.

Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT '18-27' as Caption, count(*) as Count
FROM clients
WHERE DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) < 28
AND ((clients.OmbudID = @ombud) OR (COALESCE (@ombud, '') = ''))
AND ((clients.Grupp = @grupp) OR (COALESCE (@grupp, '') = ''))
AND clients.Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut
union all

SELECT '28-37' as Caption, count(*) as Count
FROM clients
WHERE DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) >= 28
AND DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) <= 37
AND ((clients.OmbudID = @ombud) OR (COALESCE (@ombud, '') = ''))
AND ((clients.Grupp = @grupp) OR (COALESCE (@grupp, '') = ''))
union all

SELECT '38-47' as Caption, count(*) as Count
FROM clients
WHERE DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) >= 38
AND DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) <= 47
AND ((clients.OmbudID = @ombud) OR (COALESCE (@ombud, '') = ''))
AND ((clients.Grupp = @grupp) OR (COALESCE (@grupp, '') = ''))
union all

SELECT '48-57' as Caption, count(*) as Count
FROM clients
WHERE DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) >= 48
AND DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) <= 57
AND ((clients.OmbudID = @ombud) OR (COALESCE (@ombud, '') = ''))
AND ((clients.Grupp = @grupp) OR (COALESCE (@grupp, '') = ''))
union all

SELECT '58-' as Caption, count(*) as Count
FROM clients
WHERE DATEDIFF (year, clients.Födelsedatum, clients.Startdatum) >= 58
AND ((clients.OmbudID = @ombud) OR (COALESCE (@ombud, '') = ''))
AND ((clients.Grupp = @grupp) OR (COALESCE (@grupp, '') = ''))
```

Edit: Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[clients] (
[KlientID]                           INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Förnamn]                            VARCHAR (25) NULL,
[Efternamn]                          VARCHAR (25) NULL,
[Födelsedatum]                       DATE         NULL,
[OmbudID]                            INT          NULL,
[Grupp]                              TINYINT      NULL,
[Startdatum]                         DATE         NULL,
[Slutdatum]                          DATE         NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KlientID] ASC)
```

Comment: Your query is NOT changing the datatypes of your parameters. But we can't really do much here because all you provided was a query. No parameter definition, no table definition. To be honest this could be rewritten as a single query with some aggregation and grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you could simplify this query to something like this. Still have no idea what the problem you are facing is though.

```
SELECT
    Caption = case 
        when DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) < 28 AND c.Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut
            then '18-27'
        WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28 AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 37
            then '28-37'
        WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 38 AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 47
            then '38-47'
        WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 48 AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 57
            then '48-57'
        WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 58
            then '58-'
    end
    , count(*) as Count
FROM clients c
WHERE 
(
    c.OmbudID = @ombud
    OR 
    COALESCE (@ombud, '') = ''
)
AND 
(
    c.Grupp = @grupp
    OR 
    COALESCE (@grupp, '') = ''
)

group by case when DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) < 28 
        then '18-27'
    WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28
        AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 37
        then '28-37'
    WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 38
        AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 47
        then '38-47'
    WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 48
        AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 57
        then '48-57'
    WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 58
        then '58-'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on with the parameter type, but I can help with this query. There are a several things you can do that will bypass needing to UNION results from the full table multiple times.

You could do this:

```
WITH Bands As (
    SELECT 18 "Low", 27 "High"
    Union 
    SELECT 28, 37
    Union
    SELECT 38, 47
    Union
    SELECT 48, 57
    Union
    SELECT 58, NULL
)
SELECT cast(b.Low as varchar(2)) + '-' + coalesce(cast(b.High as varchar(2)),'') "Caption",
       count(*) "Count"
FROM Bands b
INNER JOIN client c ON 
        DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= b.Low
    AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= coalesce(b.High, 9999)
WHERE   c.OmbudID = COALESCE(@ombud, c.OmbudID)
    AND c.Grupp   = COALESCE(@grupp, c.Grupp)
    AND c.Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut
GROUP BY b.Low, b.High
```

I does still include a UNION, but not on your main table. I like this option because it allows you to have this be data driven. It's easy later to change the bands you need, and you could put this in a real table instead of a CTE if you want, meaning the UNION isn't really necessary at all.

But it's not the only option. You could also try this:

```
 SELECT 
      CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 27
              THEN '18-27'
          WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28
           AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 37
              THEN '28-37'
           WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28
           AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 47
              THEN '38-47'
          WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 48
           AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 57
              THEN '48-57'
          WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 58
              THEN '58-'  END "Caption",
          COUNT(*) "Count"
 FROM clients c
 WHERE   c.OmbudID = COALESCE(@ombud, c.OmbudID)
     AND c.Grupp   = COALESCE(@grupp, c.Grupp)
     AND c.Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut
 GROUP BY
     CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 27
              THEN '18-27'
          WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28
           AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 37
              THEN '28-37'
           WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28
           AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 47
              THEN '38-47'
          WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 48
           AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 57
              THEN '48-57'
          WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 58
              THEN '58-'  END
```

But the code repetition here bothers me. We can factor it out like this:

```
SELECT Caption, Count(*) "Count"
FROM (
     SELECT  CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 27
                  THEN '18-27'
              WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28
               AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 37
                  THEN '28-37'
               WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 28
               AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 47
                  THEN '38-47'
              WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 48
               AND DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) <= 57
                  THEN '48-57'
              WHEN DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) >= 58
                  THEN '58-'  END "Caption"
     FROM Clients c
     WHERE   c.OmbudID = COALESCE(@ombud, c.OmbudID)
         AND c.Grupp   = COALESCE(@grupp, c.Grupp)
         AND c.Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut
) Ages
GROUP BY Caption
```

Just be warned that in SQL-land, it's often necessary for performance to repeat code, even if it does seem tedious to write and dangerous from a maintenance standpoint.

I say this, because there is one final option that factors out even more code:

```
SELECT Caption, Count(*) "Count"  
FROM 
(
    SELECT  CASE WHEN Age <= 27 THEN '18-27'
                 WHEN Age BETWEEN 28 AND 37 THEN '28-37'
                 WHEN Age BETWEEN 38 AND 47 THEN '38-47'
                 WHEN Age BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN '48-57'
                 ELSE '58-'  END "Caption"
    FROM (
         SELECT DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) "Age"
         FROM Clients c
         WHERE   c.OmbudID = COALESCE(@ombud, c.OmbudID)
             AND c.Grupp   = COALESCE(@grupp, c.Grupp)
             AND c.Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut
    ) Ages
) Bands
GROUP BY Caption
```

With nested queries, you read from the inside out. This first factors out the Age, and then uses that Age inside the CASE statement to get the Age band, and then finally groups by the Age band to get the caption and count. It's attractive because you only need one `DATEDIFF()` and the `CASE` statement is highly readable. The nested queries can be confusing, but it's possible to improve readability and maintainability with CTEs:

```
WITH ClientAges AS (
    SELECT DATEDIFF (year, c.Födelsedatum, c.Startdatum) "Age"
    FROM Clients c
    WHERE   c.OmbudID = COALESCE(@ombud, c.OmbudID)
        AND c.Grupp   = COALESCE(@grupp, c.Grupp)
        AND c.Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut
), AgeBands As  (
    SELECT  CASE WHEN Age <= 27 THEN '18-27'
                 WHEN Age BETWEEN 28 AND 37 THEN '28-37'
                 WHEN Age BETWEEN 38 AND 47 THEN '38-47'
                 WHEN Age BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN '48-57'
                 ELSE '58-'  END "Caption"
    FROM ClientAges
)
SELECT Caption, COUNT(*) "Count"
FROM AgeBands
GROUP BY Caption
```

But. I wouldn't be surprised if Sql Server produced a less-than-optimal execution plan from this code. It has to generate a text string for every record, rather than merely grouping the record and generating the text once per group. You'll want to check this option against each of the others to see how they do.

Finally, looking at your original code, I am curious whether you want the    `Startdatum BETWEEN @start AND @slut` condition to apply only to the `<=27` band, or to all of the bands. I've been assuming it's an oversight in the other bands, but if I'm wrong it's a simple adjustment I can make if you leave a comment to the that effect.

Comment: Thanks! I have not had the time to try the new query yet. The  "@start "AND "@slut" should apply to all bands, I just left it out while I tried to find out whats wrong.